# How to preserve form field formatting (eg. Number, two decimals)

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I have a PDF with a form, where the field are formatted as number in Adobe Acrobat.
[image]

I have tried:

```
form.GetField("field_name").SetValue("123");
// Gives 123 in the PDF

form.GetField("field_name").SetValue("123", "123.00");
// Using display parameter also gives 123 in the PDF and not "123.00"
```

It look likes all values are treated as strings. Is it possible to treat the value as a number, when filling the form field value with iText?

*When I manually fill the form in Acrobat Reader and enter "123", then it appears as "123.00" when I switch focus to another field.*

EDIT:

After the comments, I leave the track of trying to set a number instead of a string and use this method:

```
void SetFormField(PdfAcroForm form, string key, string value, string? display = null) {
    var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
    if (display == null) {
        form.GetField(key).SetValue(value, font, 11f);
    } else {
        form.GetField(key).SetFontAndSize(font, 11f).SetValue(value, display);
    }
}
```

It seems to be working as expected and also set the correct font and size. I have learned "PDF are complicated, compared to a text-document"!

Comment: So this means formatting is something in the UI and cannot be used when using iText?

Comment: I feel I have allot to learn from the PDF-specification. It's a way over my head now. Is there a simple way to set the value from iText in .NET?